# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable, adding to a tuple in a loop

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

This code is part of a bigger pygame program, and this is being used to add 1 to the Y value of a falling asteroid. It first prints the correct answer with the items in the list with y value = 2, but on the second loop, i get the error message.

```
GeneratedX = []
x = (200,1)
y = (168,1)
GeneratedX.append(x)
GeneratedX.append(y)
i = True
while i == True:
    for current in GeneratedX:
        GeneratedX = (current[0],current[1] + 1)
        print(GeneratedX)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second iteration `GeneratedX` is no longer a list of tuples, instead it is a tuple 
(`GeneratedX = (current[0],current[1] + 1)`).

That's why `current` is an `int` and `current[0]` raises the `TypeError`.

A probable solution would be to use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#enumerate) in the following fashion:

```
for i, current in enumerate(GeneratedX):
    GeneratedX[i] = (current[0], current[1] + 1)
```

When used with the rest of your code outputs:

```
[(200, 2), (168, 1)]
[(200, 2), (168, 2)]
[(200, 3), (168, 2)]
[(200, 3), (168, 3)]
[(200, 4), (168, 3)]
[(200, 4), (168, 4)]
[(200, 5), (168, 4)]
[(200, 5), (168, 5)]
[(200, 6), (168, 5)]
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped alot!